# Strong typing the client model in Angular

Tags: jhipster

When we have several entities with different relationships between them (eg. `Event --1-> Venue --*-> Rooms`) JHipster generates the following for the Java back-end, which is fine :

```
@Entity
public class Event implements Serializable {
  @ManyToOne
  private Venue venue;
}

@Entity
public class Venue implements Serializable {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "venue")
  private Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Room implements Serializable {
}
```

The equivalent model in Angular is not as strongly typed. Instead, the model uses the `BaseEntity` when there is a relation :

```
export class Event implements BaseEntity {
  constructor(public venue?: BaseEntity) {}
}

export class Venue implements BaseEntity {
  constructor(public rooms?: BaseEntity[]) {}
}

export class Room implements BaseEntity {
  constructor( ) {}
}
```

With TypeScript we would highly benefit to type this code so we could navigate between objects, such as :

```
this.event.venue.rooms;
this.event.venue.rooms[0].name;
```

It would be a matter of generating the model classes without `BaseEntity` but the classes themselves :

```
export class Event implements BaseEntity {
  constructor(public venue?: Venue) {}
}

export class Venue implements BaseEntity {
  constructor(public rooms?: Room[]) {}
}

export class Room implements BaseEntity {
  constructor( ) {}
}
```

WDYT ? Is there a reason why the Angular model is not as typed as the Java one ?

Answer (score 0):

The original reason for introducing the BaseEntity(It was by me) was to avoid circular reference in Typescript. 
The build was taking unusually long and sometimes was crashing when two entities had relationships with each other resulting in the Entity model being imported in each other for the relation. This was the quick solution I could find at that time to avoid the circular reference.

Note: This was done some time back and maybe the problem doesn't exist anymore with the latest Typescript and Webpack so probably this can be revisited.